# regular express to get integer from string 

Tags: c#

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 SP1

What's the regex to get that integer between parenthesis, 100 in this case?

```
string input = "bunch of text(100):   more text here ignore the 1 or 2 ints here";
```

Comment: just really new to regexes and struggling a little to get the answer.

Comment: sorry all for updating the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
\d+
```

C# code (requires `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`, of course):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+");
string input = "bunch of text(100):   more text here";
Match m = re.Match(input);

if(m.Success) {
    // Your number is in m.Value
} else {
    // No number in the string
}
```

Comment: how do you make sure that it gets the ints between the open and close parenthesis

Comment: @rod: Use the regex: `(?<=\()\d+(?=\))`

Answer (score 2):

[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?

See this website next time: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/